# Use artifact feed from another Project (within same organisation) as upstream source

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package-restore, azure-artifacts

I have the following setup within a single organisation:

- Project A

  - Feed A (Project scoped)
- Project B

  - Feed B (Project scoped) with upstream sources:

    - ProjectA.FeedA
    - nuget.org

For now all packages are added to the Local view, which is the default. And in the Local view permissions, I configured it to 'People in '

When I create a pipeline in ProjectB, that uses the step 'Nuget restore' with feed 'ProjectB.FeedB' I always end with an error while restoring the packages:

> Response status code does not indicate success: 502 (Bad Gateway - The upstream source FeedA@Local can't be found because the upstream feed's project with id 'xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx' is deleted or has had its permissions changed. (DevOps Activity ID: XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX)).)

I figured out that in the past all artifact feeds were 'Organisation scoped'. When creating feeds now, they are 'Project-scoped'. However:

- I don't see a way to create an organisation scope feed anywhere (besides using the API).
- I don't know how to convert an existing to an organisation scope feed.
- If I'm able to configure the view in my Project-Scoped feed to be accessible to the entire organisation I guess this should work?

Any pointers on how to solve this would be very welcome!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

Go to

> Project settings > Pipeline > Settings

There you can see the option:

> Limit job authorization scope to current project

This option is also available in the settings of the organisation!

[image: Azure devops project settings screenshot]

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT Is solving it this way is the only option? According to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions#package-permissions-in-azure-pipelines) it should be enough to give reader permission to  project-level build identity. But I'm trying to do it now and it doesn't work...

Comment: Many thanks, I've been trying to figure this out all morning!

Comment: I had the same problem- the only way I could solve it, is by adding the Build service of the other project, as a member of an existing group in the project where the feed is, and then applying permissions to the feed to that group (defined in the project where the feed is). Adding permissions directly on the feed, to build service account of the other project, didn't work. I am not sure why. But that helps, without changing any of the project settings- which is better in my case.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on the topic, it looks like the only way is to use the API, as you said (emphasis mine).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/project-scoped-feeds?view=azure-devops

> If you're concerned that your project will be turned public in the
>   future and you want your feed remain private, **you can use the
>   organization-scoped feed that's automatically created when a new
>   organization is created**. Alternatively, **you can use the Create Feed
>   API to manually create a new organization-scoped feed**. You will have
>   to set the default permissions for the new feed manually either by
>   using the Feed Permission API or the Artifacts feed settings. **Creating
>   new organization-scoped feeds is not recommended**.

So you have two options:

- Use the/an existing organisation feed, or
- Manually create an organisation feed through the API (not recommended).

However, can you use a special task to authenticate with the project-scoped Azure Artifacts feed before doing your restore? We are currently using a project-scoped feed from one project in another project (within the same organisation) by using the NuGet Authenticate task:

```
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: 3.1.101
- task: NuGetAuthenticate@0
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore with nuget.config'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'nuget.config'
```

Comment: For some reason I don't have an existing organisation feed. Maybe one of my colleagues (or myself) removed when starting with azure devops.
Creating a new one through the API is something I would like to avoid.
However, when I look at the Nuget Authenticate it seems more like a cross organisation authentication...

Comment: @Joris We just use it with no options, as you can see in the sample I attached. It just works for us within the one organisation. Give it a go at least to see if it works.

Comment: I tried adding the NugetAuthenticate but has the same outcome

Answer (score 0):

> I don't see a way to create an organisation scope feed anywhere
>   (besides using the API).

For this issue ,I am afraid it is not support to create a new organization-scoped feeds through the UI. Currently, only rest API is supported to create feeds for organization scope.

Until now, in our official feature suggestion for Azure Devops forum, there has been a such suggestion exist in it: [Organisation scoped feeds](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/863132/organisation-scoped-feeds.html). You can comment and vote it there.

> If I'm able to configure the view in my Project-Scoped feed to be
>   accessible to the entire organisation I guess this should work?

For this issue , you can try to add other Project's `Build Service` groups to the feed permissions in the Permissions of Feed settings.

[image]

[image]