# Can azure pipelines accessible across projects

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are having multiple projects in Azure devops.

We would like to access the pipelines created across multiple projects.

Is that possible to access pipeline across projects or the pipelines are project specific/restricted?

Thanks

Naresh Ede

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use artifact feed from another Project (within same organisation) as upstream source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60753041/use-artifact-feed-from-another-project-within-same-organisation-as-upstream-so)

Answer (score 1):

If you use yaml pipelines and rely on multiple repositories which are stored in multi-projects, please refer to this doc: [Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops) to implement this requirement.

In addition, please disable “**Limit job authorization scope to referenced Azure DevOps repositories**” option in Project settings page by reference to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#limit-job-authorization-scope-to-referenced-azure-devops-repositories). Please note that there are also other limitation settings listed here: [Job authorization scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#job-authorization-scope).

If you use classic editor pipelines, please specify the authorization scope for a build job as “**Project Collection**”, see: [Build job authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/options?view=azure-devops#build-job-authorization-scope) scope for details. And you need to manually checkout other repositories in pipeline tasks.

Comment: @Naresh Ede Any update about this issue? If my answer helps, you could Accept it as an Answer , it could help other community members who get the same issues, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For YAML Pipelines here is the code you'd need:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: repositoryReferenceName
    type: git
    name: ProjectName/RepositoryName
```

And to reference a template it would be

```
- template: templateName.yml@repositoryReferenceName
```

Comment: The question is about accessing pipelines, not the repositories. To download pipeline artifacts I assume.